# PostgreSQL : Removing duplicates of LEFT OUTER JOIN on 3 tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, outer-join

I'm a beginner in the database.
If I have this record :

**tbl_task**

```
|-----------|
|  task_id  |
|-----------|
|   1234    |
```

**tbl_item1**

```
|-----------|-----------|
|  task_id  |   col_a   |
|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     x     |
|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     y     |
```

**tbl_item2**

```
|-----------|-----------|
|  task_id  |   col_a   |
|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     x     |
|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     y     |
```

My query so far is just a plain left join :

```
SELECT a.task_id, e.col_a as cola1, e2.col_a as cola2
FROM tbl_task a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_item1 e ON a.task_id = e.task_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_item2 e2 ON a.task_id = e2.task_id
```

And it produces duplicate data like this :

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|  task_id  |   cola1   |   cola2   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     x     |   x       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     x     |   y       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     y     |   x       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     y     |   y       |
```

How to achieve a non-duplicate record which either tbl_item1 / tbl_item2 doesn't really care which record on the first tbl is matching with the other? Like this :

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|  task_id  |   cola1   |   cola2   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     x     |   y       | <------- here cola 2 could be x / y and it doesn't matter
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     y     |   x       | <------- and here cola2 could be the value other than the data above it.
```

Any reply would be appreaciated :).
Thanks.

**UPDATE :**
Also there's possibility of another data that fills in tbl_item1 but not in tbl_item2. So the final result that i need is :

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|  task_id  |   cola1   |   cola2   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     x     |   x       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     y     |   y       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     z     |  null     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT a.task_id, e.col_a as cola1, MIN(e2.col_a) as cola2
FROM tbl_task a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_item1 e ON a.task_id = e.task_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_item2 e2 ON a.task_id = e2.task_id
GROUP BY a.task_id, e.col_a as cola1
```

Note that this does not guarantee uniqueness of records in `cola2`; typically, for your sample data, you would get:

```
|  task_id  |   cola1   |   cola2   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1234    |     x     |   x       | 
|   1234    |     y     |   x       |
```

I'm unsure how strict your requirement is in that regard, so I am still providing that solution, because it is the simplest approach (doing otherwise would notably increase the complexity of the query, as you it would require some kind of recursion).

Comment: Ah yes, i actually need the data on either cola1 / cola2 to represent what they really are in the table that match with task_id. So . . .

Comment: @DyaksaHanindito: I don't see what you mean. These values actually are in the tables on rows that match on `task_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one join

```
SELECT a.task_id, e.col_a as cola1, e2.col_a as cola2
FROM tbl_task a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_item1 e ON a.task_id = e.task_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_item2 e2 ON a.task_id = e2.task_id AND e2.col_a <> e.col_a
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But sorry, that's only removing the row with same data. Imagine if there's 3 rows in each table. It also brings you two duplicates of each data on the first table that paired with 2 other data that isn't same on the 2nd table.

Comment: So what's your logic of selecting these rows?  Seems like from the example above, you want to filter out `e2.col_a = e.col_a`